# "Identity" equivalent in Grass GIS

Tags: grass-gis, identity

In ArcGIS and SAGA GIS there is the "identity" tool, which creates a vector overlay and shows area contributions of polygons in shapefile B to the polygons in shapefile A (in the attribute table).

Which tools would be appropriate for this in Grass GIS? I tried "v.overlay", but somehow the result is not equal.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a dedicated tool, but couldn't you do a union with v.overlay (operator=or) and then exclude any areas that don't have attributes from layer_a?

Comment: Ah, yes! That's what I did first, too, but I think you have to apply another trick to get the desired result: I did the overlay as you suggested, and then I added another column in the table that I called 'area' and did a "v.to.db" with "option=area" after that.
Then, sorting is necessary for 'a_cat', done.
I found a solution, anyhow, a simpler idea is appreciated ;-)

Comment: Did you check v.select: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.select.html#overlaps-features-spatially-overlap-%28using-geos%29 ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, I used v.select with option "within" in the previous step (I did not mention that in my comment, my fault). However, correct me if I'm wrong, v.select does not yield the area contributions!?

Comment: You can use v.report or v.to.db for that